# SCAN command with spring redis template

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data

I am trying to execute "scan" command with RedisConnection. I don't understand why the following code is throwing NoSuchElementException

```
RedisConnection redisConnection = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    Cursor c = redisConnection.scan(scanOptions);
    while (c.hasNext()) {
        c.next();
    }
```

Exception:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException  at
>   java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:4189)   at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.ScanCursor.moveNext(ScanCursor.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.ScanCursor.next(ScanCursor.java:202)

Comment: To make this question more visible, you should also tag with "spring-data",  "scan" and possibly other values as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have tried this, in 1.6.6.RELEASE spring-data-redis.version. No issues, the below simple while loop code is enough. And i have set count value to 100 (more the value) to save round trip time.

```
    RedisConnection redisConnection = null;
    try {
        redisConnection = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection();
        ScanOptions options = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match(workQKey).count(100).build();

        Cursor c = redisConnection.scan(options);
        while (c.hasNext()) {
            logger.info(new String((byte[]) c.next()));
        }
    } finally {
        redisConnection.close(); //Ensure closing this connection.
    }
```

Comment: aren't you missing a call to close the Cursor `c` value as well?

Comment: Usually when connection is closed cursor will be automatically closed, not vice versa. But I agree to close the cursor, if the connection is used for long time or opening a lot of cursor in a short time in this case it is 100 and unattended.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using spring-data-redis 1.6.0-RELEASE and Jedis 2.7.2; I do think that the ScanCursor implementation is slightly flawed w/rgds to handling this case on this version - I've not checked previous versions though.

So: rather complicated to explain, but in the ScanOptions object there is a "count" field that needs to be set (default is 10). This field, contains an "intent" or "expected" results for this search. As explained (not really clearly, IMHO) [here](http://redis.io/commands/scan#the-count-option), you may change the value of count at each invocation, especially if no result has been returned. I understand this as "a work intent" so if you do not get anything back, maybe your "key space" is vast and the SCAN command has not worked "hard enough". Obviously, as long as you're getting results back, you do not need to increase this.

A "simple-but-dangerous" approach would be to have a very large count (e.g 1 million or more). This will make REDIS go away trying to search your vast key space to find "at least or near as much" as your large count. Don't forget - REDIS *is single-threaded* so **you just killed your performance**. Try this with a REDIS of 12M keys and you'll see that although SCAN may happily return results with a very high count value, it will absolutely do nothing more *during the time of that search*.

To the solution to your problem:

```
ScanOptions options = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match(pattern).count(countValue).build();
boolean done = false;

// the while-loop below makes sure that we'll get a valid cursor - 
// by looking harder if we don't get a result initially
while (!done) {
  try(Cursor c = redisConnection.scan(scanOptions)) {
    while (c.hasNext()) {
       c.next();
    }
    done = true; //we've made it here, lets go away
  } catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
    System.out.println("Going for "+countValue+" was not hard enough. Trying harder");
    options = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match(pattern).count(countValue*2).build();
  }
}
```

Do note that the ScanCursor implementation of Spring Data REDIS will properly follow the SCAN instructions and loop correctly, as much as needed, to get to the end of the loop as per documentation. I've not found a way to change the scan options within the same cursor - so there may be a risk that if you get half-way through your results and get a NoSuchElementException, you'll start again (and essentially do some of the work twice).

Of course, better solutions are always welcome :)

Comment: Drawn inspiration from https://gist.github.com/thanosa75/00b1c14105f4f42495ab -  a simple shell script that loops calling redis-cli with a valid cursor to retrieve keys via patterns

Comment: latest spring-data-redis release solves this issue; see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/pull/154

Comment: Will ScanCursor implementation of Spring Data REDIS will ensure we will not get duplicate events? since [SCAN documentation](https://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-guarantees) states in its drawback section about the duplicates can be returned.

Answer (score -2):

My old code

```
ScanOptions.scanOptions().match("*" + query + "*").count(10).build();
```

Working code

```
ScanOptions.scanOptions().match("*" + query + "*").count(Integer.MAX_VALUE).build();
```

Comment: What is wrong with the above code. As in my first code snippet, the match query builds the small data set like 10 records. In which case cursor try to find next element. With Integer.MAX_VALUE result set works for all sort of data sets.

Comment: As mentioned in my reply above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33133756/1823881), REDIS is single-threaded so you just killed your performance.